# want efcore sql syntax, fluent api method for the example from a week

Tags: ef-fluent-api

Department {int Id,string Title,Staffs}

Staff {int Id, string Name, int DeptId}

```
var DeptStaff = 
from dept in _context.Departments 
select new 
{ 
   Department= dept, 
   StaffCount = 
      (from staff in _context.Staffs 
       where staff.DeptId == dept.Id 
       select staff).Count()
}
```

Staffs is a navigation property in Department class
gives error in inner query